# Highlighting rectangle when more than half overlaps

Tags: javafx, drag

I have a JavaFX application with a pane that contains rectangles. These rectangles can be moved by dragging the mouse.

When I drag a rectangle over another rectangle, I would like the second (background) rectangle to be highlighted. This works, see code below

```
private boolean moveInProgress;
private Point2D prevPos;

public void onMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    setMouseTransparent(true);
    Point2D point = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());

    if (!moveInProgress) {
        moveInProgress = true;

        prevPos = point;
        LOG.debug("Mouse move started on location " + prevPos);
    }

    event.consume();
}

public void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    if (moveInProgress) {
        Point2D point = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
        this.toFront();

        double[] translationVector = new double[2];
        translationVector[0] = point.getX() - prevPos.getX();
        translationVector[1] = point.getY() - prevPos.getY();

        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() + translationVector[0]);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY() + translationVector[1]);

        prevPos = point;
    }

    event.consume();
}

public void onMouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    setMouseTransparent(false);

    if (moveInProgress) {
        moveInProgress = false;
    }
    event.consume();
}

public void onDragDetected(MouseEvent event) {
    startFullDrag();
    event.consume();
}

public void onMouseDragEntered(MouseDragEvent event) {
    getStyleClass().add("drag-target");
    event.consume();
}

public void onMouseDragExited(MouseDragEvent event) {
    if (getStyleClass().contains("drag-target")) {
        getStyleClass().remove("drag-target");
    }
    event.consume();
}
```

I would like to highlight the underlying rectangle when more than half of my dragging rectangle overlaps. In this picture, I would like to highlight the red rectangle, since the grey rectangle overlaps more than half of it.

The problem is that the MouseDragEntered and MouseDragExited events are fired based on my mouse position. When my mouse position is for example the black dot in the picture, my mouse events will only be fired when my mouse enters the red rectangle.

Can anyone give me some pointers how to highlight the red rectangle when during a drag action of the grey rectangle, more than half of it overlaps?

[image: Rectangles]

Comment: Not tested, but you can use `Shape.intersect(rect1, rect2)` to get a `Shape` representing the overlap: call `getBoundsInLocal()` to get the bounds of that and `getWidth()` and getHeight()` on the result to get the area of the overlap. Then compare with the area (or just width or height, as you need) of the rectangle itself to see if more than half is overlapped.

Comment: @James_D: When do you propose to do these calculations? My problem is that the event enter and exit happen on my mouse pointer location. Can I have influence on when these events are fired?

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky; you could either just do the computations whenever you move the rectangle in the `mouseDragged` listener; or you could create custom bindings (one for each of the rectangles not being dragged) when the dragging starts and dispose of them when the dragging ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have each rectangle observe the bounds of the rectangle that is being dragged. Then it's reasonably easy to do a computation using `Shape.intersect` (or by other means) to see if the rectangle is 50% covered by the rectangle being dragged. The tricky part here is adding the listeners to the rectangle being dragged and removing them again when the rectangle stops being dragged.

Here's a quick example. I think I have things set up a little differently from the way you have them set up, but you should be able to adapt this to your use case easily enough.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggingHighlightRectangles extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();
    private final ObjectProperty<Rectangle> draggingRectangle = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinSize(600, 600);

        Button newRectButton = new Button("New Rectangle");
        newRectButton.setOnAction(e -> pane.getChildren().add(createRectangle()));

        BorderPane.setAlignment(newRectButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(newRectButton, new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(pane);
        root.setBottom(newRectButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Rectangle createRectangle() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rng.nextInt(400)+100, rng.nextInt(500)+50, 100, 50);
        rect.setFill(randomColor());
        rect.getStyleClass().add("rect");

        ChangeListener<Bounds> boundsListener = (obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> {
            double myArea = rect.getWidth() * rect.getHeight() ;
            Shape intersection = Shape.intersect(draggingRectangle.get(), rect);
            Bounds intersectionBounds = intersection.getBoundsInLocal();
            double intersectionArea = intersectionBounds.getWidth() * intersectionBounds.getHeight() ;
            rect.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight"), intersectionArea >= 0.5 * myArea);
        };

        draggingRectangle.addListener((obs, oldRect, newRect) -> {
            if (oldRect != null) {
                oldRect.boundsInLocalProperty().removeListener(boundsListener);
            }
            if (newRect != null && newRect != rect) {
                newRect.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(boundsListener);
            }
            rect.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight"), false);
        });

        class MouseLocation { double x, y ; }
        MouseLocation mouseLocation = new MouseLocation();

        rect.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            draggingRectangle.set(rect);
            rect.toFront();
            mouseLocation.x = e.getX() ;
            mouseLocation.y = e.getY() ;
        });

        rect.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            rect.setX(rect.getX() + e.getX() - mouseLocation.x);
            rect.setY(rect.getY() + e.getY() - mouseLocation.y);
            mouseLocation.x = e.getX() ;
            mouseLocation.y = e.getY() ;
        });

        rect.setOnMouseReleased(e -> draggingRectangle.set(null));

        return rect ;
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return Color.rgb(rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My stylesheet, style.css, just contains

```css
.rect:highlight {
    -fx-fill: yellow ;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea to listen to the property bounds. This made me find my solution.